# Conditional construct with parameter and eval

Tags: bash, eval

Consider the following code. If I remove the `eval` and instead just write `if "$1"` it doesn't work. Is it possible to get rid of the `eval`?

```
assert () {
  if eval "$1"      #Is it possible to get rid of the eval?
  then
    echo "Assertion OK:  \"$1\""
  else
    echo "Assertion FAILED:  \"$1\""
  fi
}

assert " [[ /tmp/a = /tmp/* ]]"
```

Comment: No, it is not. You can't pass arbitrary code as an argument, so you need to "encode" your code as a string; it's `eval`'s job to "decode" it and execute it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could replace `eval "$1"` with `bash -c "$1"`, but I doubt that's what you had in mind. (Depending on what `$1` contains, running a new process could produce different results if the code in `$1` depends on the value of some local variables that won't be passed to a new process. It would also swallow any side effects, such as variable assignments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a useful `assert` function without using `eval`:

```
function assert
{
    local IFS   # Protect "$*" against an unusual IFS value in the caller

    if "$@"; then
        printf 'Assertion OK: "%s"\n' "$*"
    else
        printf 'Assertion FAILED: "%s"\n' "$*"
    fi
}
```

Example uses:

```
assert [ -f /etc/passwd ]   # OK
assert [ ! -f /etc/group ]  # FAILED

var1='a b'
var2='a b'
var3='-c'
assert [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]    # OK
assert [ "$var2" = "$var3" ]    # FAILED

assert grep -q '^guest:' /etc/passwd    # Maybe OK, maybe FAILED
```

The `assert` function works when the command (`$1`) is a user-defined function (e.g. `dostuff`), a Bash built-in command (e.g. `[` or `test`), or an external command (e.g. `grep`).

Because of the way that Bash processes lines of code, the function does not work if the command is a Bash [reserved word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reserved-Word-Index.html) (aka "keyword").  See the accepted answer to [What's the difference between shell builtin and shell keyword?](https://askubuntu.com/q/445749) for excellent relevant information.  In particular, it covers important differences between `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]`.  The standard Bash documentation is poor in this area.

`[[` is a reserved word, so this does not work:

```
  assert [[ /tmp/a = '/tmp/*' ]]          # Error: '[[' command  not found
```

Since Bash does special processing on the code inside `[[ ... ]]`, I don't think it is possible to modify the `assert` function to make `assert [[ ...` work in all cases.  One way to work around the problem, without using `eval`, is to use `[` instead of `[[` in cases where their functionality overlaps (file access testing, simple string comparisions, ...) and use special `assert_*` functions for special functionality of `[[`.  For instance, this function tests (glob) pattern matching:

```
function assert_match
{
    local -r str=$1
    local -r pat=$2

    # shellcheck disable=SC2053 # (Bad warning about not quoting $pat)
    if [[ $str == $pat ]]; then
        printf 'assert_match OK: "%s" matches "%s"\n' "$str" "$pat"
    else
        printf 'assert_match FAILED: "%s" does not match "%s"\n' "$str" "$pat"
    fi
}
```

Example uses:

```
assert_match /tmp/a '/tmp/*'    # match OK
assert_match /tmp/a '/tmp/b*'   # match FAILED
```

An `assert_rematch` function for regular expression matches (`[[ ... =~ ... ]]`) might also be useful.

Comment: Why the [legacy ksh / pre-POSIX](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) function declaration syntax? (See the last table in the link, not the first one).

Comment: BTW, I would probably use `local cmd_str; printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"` and then print error messages with `${cmd_str% }` instead of `$*`; that way you don't lose the distinction between `assert foo "argument here"` and `assert foo "argument" "here"`, don't need to mess with IFS, and let users copy-and-paste strings from your error messages to the command line if they want to try running something themselves.